# Здравствуйте. Нужна помощь с выводом радарной диаграммы ботом в телеграм чат. В Python новичок - перепробовал многое

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

```
import telebot
import pygal

bot = telebot.TeleBot('**********************************')

def Radar():
  view = pygal.Radar()
  view.title = 'Радарная карта'
  view.add('A', \[31,56,34,67,34\])
  view.add('B', \[23,18,57,45,35\])
  view.add('C', \[14,45,76,34,76\])  
  view.render_to_file('view.svg')



@bot.message_handler(commands=\["start"\])
def start(m, res=False):
    bot.send_message(m.chat.id, 'Бот запущен. Введите команду /graf для вывода графика')

@bot.message_handler(commands=\["graf"\])
def send_photo_file_id(message):
  bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo='view.svg', caption='График')
    

bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)][1]][1]
```

[image]

Comment: Символы "[![" в начале кода поставил случайно - в коде их нет...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo=open('view.svg', "rb"), caption='График')
```